# While(true) loop will not break, runs forever

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Lab11bst
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      System.out.println("Pick A Card, Any Card");
      System.out.println();     
      Deck deck = new Deck();
      System.out.println(deck);
   }
}

class Card
{
   private String suit;
   private String rank;
   private int pointValue;

   public Card(String s, String r, int pV)
   {
      suit = s;
      rank = r;
      pointValue = pV;
   }

   public String suit()      { 
      return suit; }
   public String rank()      { 
      return rank; }
   public int pointValue()   { 
      return pointValue; }

   public boolean matches(Card otherCard) 
   {
      return otherCard.suit().equals(this.suit())
          && otherCard.rank().equals(this.rank())
          && otherCard.pointValue() == this.pointValue();
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return rank + " of " + suit + " (Point Value = " + pointValue + ")";
   }
}

class Deck 
{
   private Card[] cards;
   private int size;
   private Card[] newcards;

   private String[] Suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
   private String[] Ranks = {"Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
   private int[] pointValues = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11};

   public Deck() 
   {
      size = 52;
      cards = new Card[size];

      int index = 0;

      for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++)
      {
         for (int r = 0; r < 13; r++)
         {
            cards[index] = new Card(Suits[s], Ranks[r], pointValues[r]);
            index +=1;
         }
      }

      //SwapShuffle();
      OneBigShuffle();
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      String temp = "";
      for (int k = 0; k <= size -1; k++)
      {
         temp += cards[k];
         temp += "\r\n";
      }
      return temp;
   }

   private void SwapShuffle()
   {
      int uno;
      int due;
      Card temp;

      for (int w = 0; w < 1000; w++)
      {
         uno =  (int)( Math.random() *52 );
         due = (int)( Math.random() *52 );

         temp = cards[uno];
         cards[uno] = cards[due];
         cards[due] = temp;
      }
   }

    public static boolean repeat (int[] array, int e) 
         {
        boolean result = false;
        for (int i : array)
        {
            if (i == e)
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

   private void OneBigShuffle()
   {
      newcards = new Card[size];
      int spot;
      int[]  prevSpots = new int[size];
      boolean running = true;

      for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
         {
            while(true)
            {
            spot = (int)( Math.random() *52 );
            if (repeat(prevSpots, spot) == false)
               {
              break;
               }
            }
            newcards[k]  = cards[spot];
            prevSpots[k] = spot;
         }
         cards = newcards;
   }
}
```

There could totally be a stupid mistake in there somewhere, but my while loop refuses to terminate. My goal for the OneBigShuffle method is to have the while loop run until Math.random generates a number that is not contained in the prevSpots array (the array is checked with the "repeat" method). However, the program seems to run indefinitely, despite the if statement with the break. I have also tried a while(condition) format, where the condition is set to false instead of the break. That resulted in an error where it said "spot might not have been initialized". the whole program is above, but this seems to be teh problem area below:

```
for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
         {
            while(true)
            {
            spot = (int)( Math.random() *52 );
            if (repeat(prevSpots, spot) == false)
               {
              break;
               }
            }
            newcards[k]  = cards[spot];
            prevSpots[k] = spot;
         }
```

SIZE IS 52, so the array has 52 spots!

Comment: `size` seems to come out of nowhere, `newcards` doesn't have a type, ... - does this even compile?

Comment: hold on ill put in the whole program

Comment: Try to update the code in your question so that it becomes a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that will make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: The `repeat` method returns true when matched, but your logic in the `while` loop tests for a false indication to terminate the loop. Appears these tests are opposite when they should be the same.

Comment: FYI: shuffling cards (or anything) has well-established algorithms, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: I couldn't find the `repeat()` method because I searched for "repeat(". It really helps to format code correctly. Also using `!` is better than `== false` and a `do`-`while` loop is better than `while (true) { ... if (...) { break; } }`. Finding those last few spots may not be performant (I think it's of the order of a thousand times around the loop, which you may get away with but isn't good habit).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you check the whole array each time, not just the part that you have filled.

The array is initially 52 cells containing 0.

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬─────┬───┐
│ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │ ... │ 0 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴─────┴───┘
```

You pick a number, say 6. It checks all the 52 cells - it finds that none of them contains 6. That's good, so it puts 6 in the first spot.

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬─────┬───┐
│ 6 │ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │ ... │ 0 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴─────┴───┘
```

You pick another number, say 19. It checks all 52 cells. The values it has are 6 and 0. OK, 19 is OK, it puts it in the next cell.

```
┌───┬────┬───┬───┬─────┬───┐
│ 6 │ 19 │ 0 │ 0 │ ... │ 0 │
└───┴────┴───┴───┴─────┴───┘
```

And so on. The problem is that you'll pick every number except 0. Every time it picks 0, it checks it, and there is already a 0 in the array. Once you have filled in all the other numbers (1-51), you can't pick any other number but 0. But you already have 0, because you check the whole array!

You have to check for "repeat" only up to - and not including - `k`.

By the way, this is a very bad way to shuffle an array. Its time complexity can be near infinite, depending on the random number generator. The most efficient shuffle algorithm is:

- Fill the array with the cards in their natural order from 0 to 51.
- For `num` in descending order from 51 to 0:

  - Pick a random number `rand` between 0 and `num` inclusive.
  - Exchange the cards between `array[rand]` and `array[num]`

When you finish, your array is shuffled - because in each turn, you picked a random cell that has not been picked yet. Because if it was picked, it was already exchanged for another number that was not picked.

Answer (score 0):

`repeat()` always checks the entire array, which contains 52 zeroes at the beginning. This way zero itself can never be placed in the array.

It should get `k`:

```
public static boolean repeat (int[] array, int e, int k) 
{
    boolean result = false;
    //for (int i : array)
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++) // <-- loop changed
    {
        if (array[i] == e) // <-- i became array[i]
        {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and the result is still going to be slow as the random generator has to roll one of fewer and fewer numbers as the loop (the outer one, in `OneBigShuffle()`) proceeds.

Consider referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle about shuffling.

---

Side note: the original could work too after all, if the array would contain invalid positions by default:

```
int[] prevSpots = new int[size];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    prevSpots[i] = -1; // or any other value what is not in 0...51
}
```